# Observing a runtime error while trying to run a code

Tags: c++, function, stack, max

I am getting the following error for my solution to this leetcode problem:

https://leetcode.com/problems/maximal-rectangle/

```
Line 1034: Char 9: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'int' (stl_vector.h)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:1043:9
```

Here is my code:

```cpp
int area(vector<int> heights) {
    stack<int> s;
    int n = heights.size();
    int res = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
        while(!s.empty() && heights[s.top()] >= heights[i]) {
            int temp = s.top();
            s.pop();
            int a = heights[temp]*((s.empty()) ? (i) : (i-s.top()-1));
            res = max(res, a);
        }
        s.push(heights[i]);
    }
    while(!s.empty()) {
        int temp = s.top();
        s.pop();
        int a = heights[temp]*((s.empty()) ? (n) : (n-s.top()-1));
        if(a > res) res = a;
    }
    return res;
}
    
int maximalRectangle(vector<vector<char>>& matrix) {
    vector<int> heights;
    for(int i = 0; i<matrix[0].size(); i++) {
        heights[i] = (matrix[0][i] - '0');
    }
    int res = area(heights);
    for(int i = 1; i<matrix.size(); i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j<matrix[i].size(); j++) {
            if(matrix[i][j] == '0') heights[j] = 0;
            else heights[j] += 1;
        }
        res = max(res, area(heights));
    }
    return res;
}
```

Please help me identify my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The vector `heights` in the function `maximalRectangle` doesn't have any elements by default, so you cannot access `heights[i]`.

You should allocate enough element first. You can allocate elements by (for example) specifying the number of elements to allocate in the constructor. If all elements of the vector `matrix` have the same size, it can be like this:

```
vector<int> heights(matrix[0].size());
```

Comment: Ohhhh my godd!! That was such a silly mistake. Thanks for pointing it out! I can't live with myself now :/